# Skip triggering Airflow DAG if any of previous instance is running or failed

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that runs every hour, say, 7:10, 8:10, 9:10, 10:10.. etc.
If any instance of DAG run takes beyond an hour to complete, I need only the next scheduled run to be triggered after the completion time.

Ex: if 7:10 run completes at 8:15, the next run should be the 9:10 one and 8:10 run shouldn't be triggered when the 7:10 run completes.

if 7:10 run completes at 9:30, the next run should be the 10:10 one and 8:10,9:10 runs shouldn't be triggered when the 7:10 run completes

Also, if any of the runs fail, someone will intervene, cleanup and marks the DAG success.
Until then, subsequent runs shouldn't be triggered and after the failed one is marked success manually, next scheduled run should be triggered at the scheduled time.

Ex: if 7:10 run failed at 7:30, and marked success manually at 8:45, the next run should be at 9:10.

How can this be done in Airflow.

Thanks

Comment: Set the scheduler to `None` of your current dag, create another dag that first checks the status of the dag (whether it's completed or not) and then triggers the same dag (apply your logic in the PythonOperator). Schedule the same as per your need to monitor the one that needs to be executed on hourly basis.

Comment: Agreed with **@neilharia7**, and you can have this behaviour with a single DAG: let the first task be a `PythonOperator` or custom operator (perhaps along the lines of `ShortCircuitOperator`) and then use it to check the status of last `DagRun` for deciding to skip current run using `AirflowSkipException`

Comment: Thanks @y2k-shubham - Having a check on previous run during the current run worked for me.